# How to count most occurring word from a set of documents then perform sub aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

From an **Elasticsearch query**, I am able to produce let's say around 5000 documents
Now, I'm trying to determine which non-stop words (stop words are auxiliary verbs / non-significant words) are appearing the most.

So I tried this query using the **significant_text** aggregation

```
$params2 = [
    'index' => ["web", "print"],
    'type'  => 'index',
    'from'  => 0,
    'size'  => 10000,
    'filter_path' => ['aggregations'],
    'body'  => [
        "query" => //omitted query here
        'aggs' => [
            'SIGNIFICANT' => [
                "significant_text" => [
                    "field" => "content"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Unfortunately, it still displays some `garbage words` that are not **significant** to me

[image]

**My Questions:**
1. Is there an alternative for `significant_text` aggregation?

2. I also want to perform a `terms` sub-aggregation after this `significant_text` main aggs, because I want to combine a query to know the popular words, and then filter the documents according to the other fields

Would greatly appreciate it if you have an idea how to perform this desired process and output